# Convert strings in numpy array using title attribute

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array with city names with different combinations of upper and lower case spellings. The city names need to be converted so that if the city was spelled "NEW YORK" it would become "New York".
I have a working solution, however I was wondering if there is any simpler or more elegant way of doing the same thing

```
n = 0
for x in cities:
    cities[n] = x.title()
    n = n+1
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with this code. May I ask why you are trying to change it?

Comment: Just wondering if there is a way to make the code more concise. Why use four lines of code if the same can be done with one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it one liner

```
cities = [x.title() for x in cities]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Guy solution is better is this case, but you should also be familiar with this structure, that can be helpful in others:

```
for n, x in enumerate(cities):
    cities[n] = x.title()
```

which creates the n as 0, and increases it by 1 in every iteration.